# Selective ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say I'm having a table 'Users'.
A user can exist 3 times (records) in my table, in 3 different states (state1, state2, state3).
First state1 will be created, then state2, ...
If state3 exists, I don't want to look at state1 and state2 anymore, but I'll have to keep them in my table, for later purposes.
All 3 records have the same uuid.

If I want to collect all users, I can't use User.all (because he will give me all 3 states for the same user).

Is there a short solution for this in my model? Now I'm collecting all uuid's and for each uuid I'll check which is the latest state, then I put those records in an array. 
Problem with this array is that it is just 'an array', instead of an ActiveRecord object.

```
@uuid = []
@users = [] #will contain only the latest states at the end

User.all.each do |u|
  @uuid << u.uuid unless @uuid.includes?(u.uuid)
end

@uuid.each do |u|
  if user = User.find_by_state_and_uuid(3, u)
     @users << user
  elsif user = User.find_by_state_and_uuid(2, u)
     @users << user
  elsif user = User.find_by_state_and_uuid(1, u)
     @users << user
  end
end
```

Any ideas how I can translate this logic to an ActiveRecord object?

In short: User.magic_function to return only the latest state of each uuid

Thanks in advance!
Wouter

Answer (score 1):

If you plan ahead, you can always sort on your state and return the "highest" one. This works well if you have a linear progression from one to the next. As an example:

```
user = User.where(:uuid => u).order('users.state DESC').first
```

For more complicated transitions you're not going to be able to use this trick. You could try using a different column for ordering, such as fetching the last by `created_at` time.

From a design perspective it seems highly unusual to have several user records in different states. A better plan might be to split out the state-driven part of the user record into a separate table and do the state tracking there, everything linked back to a singular user record.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)? You should be able to create a scope for each User state, and then use those for querying.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
User.get_user(state, uuid)
```

And make the scope in your user model :

```
  scope :get_user, lambda { |*args| { :conditions => ["state = ? AND uuid = ?",args.first , args.second ] }}
```